# Emulate php's MySQL functions with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I would like to know if it's possible to make MySQL querys with only JS functions or ajax calls.

I should tell you than I'm starting to make things in PHP and it's getting a bit difficult due to the fact that I don't have any idea of it and I'm "wasting" too much time I could use to improve in another language.

Would it be a good idea or the worst I could ever had?

Comment: You can try to use node.js.

Comment: And what about an http server like Xampp?

Comment: PHP is brilliantly simple. Even I can do it (sort of), so I'd persevere if I were you.

Comment: xampp is not a webserver, it's a pre-packaged set of softwares that include a webserver (apache). You can use node.js with apache. However, I think you meant to use mysql from js running in the browser directly, which is a no-go.

Comment: Why can't I do that? Does the browser don't add this kind of functionality (like working with the file-system) or it is possible to do it with the language but the browser directly blocks it by default? How does JS works in a browser?

Comment: Technically you can access a mysql server and talk to it using raw sockets (if the browser supports raw sockets, and imho it is only experimental). But you would need to store the username and password in a way that the browser and as of that the whole world can read it. So everyone could log into your mysql server with those login data.

Comment: So it wouldn't be a nice idea to implement it in client-side? What about server-side? Is it possible to build a server with JS?